# How to create timer in WinApi (C++)?

Tags: c++, winapi, timer

How to create timer in WinApi (C++)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call the [SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.  This allows you to specify a callback function, or to have Windows post you a WM_TIMER message.

Comment: as per nobugz - this will not work in console applications or non gui threads. threads must be pumping messages to generate SetTimer callbacks.

Comment: SetTimer is not a high resolution (i.e., <20ms) timer. CreateTimerQueueTimer is better but consume more resources.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot not know this if you write GUI code.  Which makes it likely you want to use CreateTimerQueueTimer().

Comment: Yes, CreateTimerQueueTimer is your friend.  Beware that the callback is executed on a threadpool thread so use proper locking.

Comment: CreateWaitableTimer can also be used in console application.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682492(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 4):

[SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906(VS.85).aspx).  A window handle is needed, and the timer will not be delivered if you aren't pumping messages.

Answer (score 4):

A Good Example for CreateTimerQueueTimer : [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687003%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Another is [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/timers_intro.aspx#QueueTimers)

Answer (score 2):

call the `setTimer()` Function. Suppose I called

```
SetTimer(hWnd,POST_CBIT_TIMER,500,NULL);
```

Call back function is

```
UINT nIdEvent ;//global member variable

case WM_TIMER:

if(nIDEvent == POST_CBIT_TIMER)
{

KillTimer(hParent,POST_CBIT_TIMER);


}
break;
```