# Inline assembly, out instruction

Tags: c++, assembly, io, x86

I am trying to export a .dll file and trying to use it in my c# application to write a data to a port. In my .cpp file (to create a .dll) if I use "out" command it gives "error C2415: improper  operand type" error message. Do you have any idea why i cannot use this "out" command? ("mov" command is working well btw)

See my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void enableWatchDog()
    _asm {
          out 66,41
          out 62,4
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the platform? Windows? If so, are you writing a driver? If not, `out` won't ever work, your program will just force-close.

Comment: If you try to create a timer under Windows, please look at [How to create timer in WinApi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128620/how-to-create-timer-in-winapi-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`out` has six forms:

- `out imm8, AL`
- `out imm8, AX`
- `out imm8, EAX`
- `out DX, AL`
- `out DX, AX`
- `out DX, EAX`

Your usages match none of them. Perhaps this would work (not tested):

```
mov al, 41
out 66, al
mov al, 4
out 62, al
```

I don't have too much experience with IO ports on x86, but from what I've been able to find, 66 and 62 seem a little suspicious to me. Shouldn't they be 66h and 62h? 41h (could be two flags set, or ASCII 'A') also makes a little more sense to me than 41 (a rather arbitrary number).

Answer (score 1):

Assembly is not a high level language, where you can plug an arbitrary expression anywhere. The `out` command can only take an `Ax` register for a second operand, where Ax means AL, AX, or EAX. So reformulate like this:

```
mov al, 41
out 66, al
mov al, 4
out 62, al
```

The `out` command is privileged; it only works in kernel level drivers on Windows, trying to do it in a regular program will get you an "Invalid operation" error.

Answer (score 0):

What target platform are you using for your C++ dll? You need to compile to x86 code, not CLR.

Comment: The error  "error C2415: improper operand type" is clearly about the out instruction, not CLR vs native code.