# Is there a Timer class in native c++ similar to Extctrls::TTimer from c++ builder?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to convert some code from c++ builder to vc++. I have TTimer used as a parent class. I can't find something similar or equivalent in vc++ native. Can someone guide me where I can find these?

Comment: Most C++ UI tool sets will have a timer class. If you start with raw C++ then you'll need to build it yourself.

Comment: It depends on what libraries you use. It can be done easily with Windows API alone, for some more info check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128620/how-to-create-timer-in-winapi-c

Comment: @Adrian, that seems like a GUI control. I'm using a win32 application. I basically I want to use the timer inside a class method to call another member method when the interval is up. So far in my search it SetTimer() or SetWaitableTimer() which is not recognizing the member function.

Comment: I have changed to use just sleep from windows.h instead.